# How to word this boolean parameter in a function

Tags: c++, boolean

I am trying to create a treasure map that will show the treasure location at the end of the game. It can't show the treasure map when the user is playing the game. My professor said to use a boolean value to do this; however, I have no clue on how to go about this. The name of my boolean value is ShowTreasure. My code needs to print a star instead of a "T" if the boolean value is false. How should I assign ShowTreasure to be true or false? This is my code:

```
void PrintMap(bool ShowTreasure)
{

   char map[Y_DIM][X_DIM]= {};


   for (int row = 0; row < Y_DIM; row++)
   {
      for (int col = 0; col < X_DIM; col++)
      {
         cout << map[row][col];
         if ((col == TreasureX && row == TreasureY)) && ShowTreasure)
                cout << "T";
         else 
         cout << "*";
      }
   cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: `ShowTreasure = true` or `ShowTreasure = false` change the value of your `ShowTreasure` value. The question of where in your code you would change its value is another matter entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PrintMap()` may be called two ways:

```
PrintMap( false );    // 1

PrintMap( true );     // 2
```

I am guessing that your professor might want #1 when the player is in the middle of the game and #2 when the game is over.

Comment: Should I still have to set ShowTreasure to true or false separately?

Comment: Inside `PrintMap()`? Perhaps, no, it is already set by the caller of `PrintMap()`.

Comment: It still keeps printing the treasure location even when I call the function as you said above.

Comment: That might be because of the unconditional statement `cout << map[row][col];`. Try removing that.

Comment: It is printing correctly as of now! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @savannaalexis: Thanks, glad to know that. I am lucky that the guesswork worked :-).

Answer (score 0):

> How should I assign ShowTreasure to be true or false?

```
ShowTreasure = true; // assigns true to ShowTreasure
ShowTreasure = false; // assigns false to ShowTreasure
```